# Split data into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm extracting customer data from a legacy system stored in a MSSQL 2012 database.  In this table couples are held under a single customer code using a Name_1 and Name_2 field.  It looks something like this:

```
ID      |   Name_1     |      Name_2     |     Address
-----      --------          ---------        ---------
DOE001  | John Doe     |   Jane Doe      |  1234 Somewhere St.
```

Our new system needs to have this information separated.  They would be separate records with the same ID but a differentiating field called "Address ID".  I'm looking for a way to split the information like the following:

```
    Customer ID     |   Name      |     Address        |     Address ID
   -----------         -------         ----------        --------------
       DOE001       |   John Doe  | 1234 Somewhere St  |       01
       DOE001       |   Jane Doe  | 1234 Somewhere St  |       02
```

I'd appreciate any help generating a query that would split the information into the multiple rows and, if possible generate the new Address ID.  For each new Customer ID the Address ID would begin at 01 and then increment if required.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, Name_1 AS Name, Address FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Name_2 AS Name, Address FROM myTable
)

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID, Name, Address) AS [Address ID] FROM CTE
```

First this selects every row into two rows, split on the names. Next it generates a unique `[Address ID]`, based on the sorting by (in this case) `ID, Name, Address` ascending.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Assuming you will have only 2 name fields,

```
SELECT v.*
FROM t
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES (id, name_1, Address,'01'), (id, name_2, Address, '02')
) 
v (id, name, Address, Address_id)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2f5e/1)

Comment: +1 Nice solution, however the values `01` and `02` are not really `ID`'s  since they'll repeat on every `[Customer ID]`, are they?

Comment: @Aquillo, based on OPs question it looks like there will be only two rows for each customer id, i don't think we need row_number when we know that dataset will always return only 2 rows. Check my SQL demo, it repeats for every customer id :) And OP mentioned that he wants address id to begin at 01 for each new customer

Comment: In that case `([Customer ID], [Address ID])` would be the `PRIMARY KEY`. OP should really consider what would suit his case better. :)

Comment: @Aquillo, yes i agree

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (ID VARCHAR(10), Name_1 VARCHAR(100), Name_2 VARCHAR(100), [Address] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('DOE001', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe', '1234 Somewhere St.')

SELECT
    ID AS CustomerID
    , Name
    , [Address]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name) AS AddressID
FROM #temp
UNPIVOT (Name FOR ContactName IN (Name_1, Name_2)) AS Names
```

I am fond of the UNPIVOT approach.

Here is a link to a post that explains how you can use UNPIVOT.
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/04/23/unpivot.aspx